# Grafana alerting not working with Hawkular services

Tags: grafana, hawkular

We have setup Grafana and installed Hawkular plugin to connect with Hawkular services. It worked & shown some metrics. When an alert is configured via Grafana UI, it shown following error in Grafana UI:

> tsdb.HandleRequest() error Could not find executor for data source
>   type: hawkular-datasource

Is there any option to get alerts either through Grafana or Hawkular?

Answer (score 3):

As AussieDan mentions, alerting is not available with the hawkular datasource or other datasource plugins.

However hawkular has its own alerting engine that you could use instead, though it's not visible from grafana dashboards (might be visible as annotations in the future), example here http://www.hawkular.org/hawkular-services/docs/quickstart-guide/#_step_3_add_alerting

Comment: There is alerts tab showing in grafana but on setting conditions it shows errors. Alert condition is checked and showing warning in UI. But not received email as per that.

Answer (score 0):

Grafana currently does not support alerts through datasource plugins, because they are written in javascript and can't be executed on the server which uses golang.